# Propensity Score Matching with pooling of panel data

Tags: propensity-scores

I want to conduct a Propensity Score Matching with a Diff in Diff strategy (or please suggest if there are any other approach/s I should be following) **to assess the causal impact of ventures changing their locations on net profits**. (Software – Stata).

I have a panel dataset (2004 – base year, final survey 2011) of ventures which started in 2004. Some ventures changed their locations in 2005, some in 2006 etc. I have the net profits of these ventures (if they are in business) for all the years. Thus, for examples sake taking ventures that relocated in 2005 as the focus, use the 2004 variables for calculating the propensity score (pscore command) and matching based on it followed by the attn or attk type commands to calculate the treatment effect. The dependent variable would be the difference in net profits between 2006 and 2004: the post – pre treatment net income difference, with relocation (dummy indicator) and a few other covariates as the independent variable. I can do this separately for each year – 2005, 2006, 2007 ….. but I would like to combine these in the hope that it may make the standard errors tighter (out of 3140 ventures ~300 have moved in between 2005 – 2010, ~50 moves per annum) and other benefits (about which I am not sure but know that more data should be better). However, I am struggling with the following concerns:

1. How can I combine these separate analyses into one analyses? I want to keep the trtd and control observations from the same year (ventures that moved in 2006 should be matched with ventures that did not move in 2006 and the matching will be on 2005 pre treatment variables. I do not want ventures that moved in 2005 being matched with ventures in 2004 or 2006, 2007 etc.)
2. If I combine as discussed in point 1 above, and I use age as a covariate in the attk, attn etc. regressions and not in the pscore regression – will I get valid results? Since I will have ventures with different ages in the same regression (and the pscore did not have age as a covariate).
3. Finally, how to handle closures in controls? Say for ventures that moved in 2005, I matched based on 2004 pre treatment variables. However, some of these control ventures closed down in say 2005 or 2006 (these closures could be due to bad outcomes or good outcomes -  for ex bankruptcy – bad outcome or due to merger or acquisition which is generally due to the fact that the venture was doing well – good outcome. In any case the net profit data is quantitative and this data would be qualitative). In 2004 there were ~3000 ventures and by end of the survey there were ~1500 ventures still in operation, hence this may be a significant issue. If I ignore these closed ventures, I am thinking this would lead to a bias ………. Any thoughts on what can be done?